# Free dynamically created 3d array in C

Tags: c

None of the answers I have found seem to address my issue. I am creating a dynamic 3d array in C and later freeing it. I can store and later access the data stored in this array using a nested for loop but I get an access violation when trying to free it using the same nested for loop setup. Where am I going wrong?

```
unsigned char ***buff1;
int r, c;
someFunction(&buff1, &r, &c);
for(int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < c; ++j)
  {
    free(buff1[i][j]);
  }
  free(buff1[i]);
}
free(buff1);


someFunction(unsigned char**** buff, int *nR, int *nC)
{
  ...
  *buff = (SQLCHAR***)malloc(*nR * sizeof(SQLCHAR**));
  for(int i = 0; i < *nR; ++i)
  {
    (*buff)[i] = (SQLCHAR**)malloc(*nC * sizeof(SQLCHAR**));
    for(int j = 0; j < *nC; ++j)
    {
      (*buff)[i][j] = (SQLCHAR*)malloc(256);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how `r` and `c` are initialized — or how `*nR` and `*nC` are initialized in `someFunction()` if that's where the initialization occurs.  It seems a little odd to pass an `unsigned char ****` and then cast the return value from `malloc()` using `SQLCHAR` instead of `unsigned char`.  There are those who'd say using a cast at all is bad; I'm not wholly in that camp, but I do think consistency is good and the code is not consistent as written.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple things are wrong:

```
unsigned char**** buff
```

**What is this, if not wrong?** (Well, OK, not technically, but stylistically anyway...)

```
(SQLCHAR*)malloc(256);
```

isn't any better either, since [you must not cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

The third mistake is that you don't have a 3D array. You have a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer. Ewww. Ugly. Why not allocate a true 3D array instead?

```
size_t xsize, ysize, zsize; // initialize these!
unsigned char (*arr)[ysize][zsize] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * xsize);
```

Then all you need to do in order to free it is:

```
free(arr);
```

**Honestly, isn't this way better?**

Comment: That does look much better. xsize and ysize are both determined at runtime and will not work this way.

Comment: Oh, and before Eric Postpischil points out that this isn't a true array either: that's right, it's a pointer to the first element of an array of type `unsigned char [xsize][ysize][zsize]`, which (obviously) points to a contiguous block of memory which can be treated as an array (except that pointers are not arrays, so the usual warnings about the `sizeof` and the `&` operators apply). A true 3D array, strictly speaking, would be `unsigned char [xsize][ysize][zsize]`, but that's not dynamically alocated.

Comment: @NoleFan81 Excuse me, but do you happen to be stuck in 1989? VLAs are standard in C99.

Comment: OP wanted to return the allocated array from the function; i don't see how you can do it when using a VLA

Comment: @NoleFan81 What do you mean by that? Why do you have "no choice"? Are you obliged to use a compiler which doesn't support C99? (If so, you should have mentioned that well before diving deep into the question.)

Comment: Also, what's the reason for the (edit: now-revoked) downvote? I can assure everybody that this answer is correct - both technically and conceptually.

Comment: I removed my downvote: did some tests and actually figured the syntax out. Not easy (unless you edit OP's code by removing `someFunction` altogether).

Comment: @anatolyg Conversely, it's pretty trivial: `unsigned char (*p)[y][z] = theAllocatorFunc();`. Also, if **you** can't figure out the syntax, that's not my fault. Don't judge others before having made sure that it's not indeed you who made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I try you code in this way,and it works good:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int  someFunction (unsigned char**** buff, int *nR, int *nC)
{
  int i,j;
  *buff = (unsigned char ***)malloc(*nR * sizeof(char**));
  for(i = 0; i < *nR; ++i)
  {
    (*buff)[i] = (unsigned char**)malloc(*nC * sizeof(char**));
    for(j = 0; j < *nC; ++j)
    {
      (*buff)[i][j] = (unsigned char*)malloc(256);

      (*buff)[i][j][0] ='1';
    }
  }
}


int main()
{
unsigned char ***buff1;
int r = 3, c= 2,i,j;
someFunction(&buff1, &r, &c);
for( i = 0; i < r; ++i)
{
  for(j = 0; j < c; ++j)
  {
        printf("        %c",buff1[i][j][0]);
    free(buff1[i][j]);
  }
  free(buff1[i]);
}
free(buff1);
}
```

So, maybe the mistake is not happening in the code you are showing to us.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty buggy. For starters you are calling `someFunction(&buff1, &r, &c)` while that function expects `int`s and not `int *`s. Later you dereference nR and nC and they aren't pointers.

I guess you should be getting some nasty warnings when compiling.